# snapd randomly takes up all the available memory

Tags: ubuntu, snappy, snapcraft

I'm using snaps in ubuntu 20.04. Every so often, even several times a day all of a sudden my computer freezes as the memory usage foes to 100% with all available memory taken by snapd. I tried killing the snapd process but it wouldn't make any difference, strangely. The only way to recover is to restart the system.

Anyone has had a similar problem? How to further debug it? Are there any logs I could look at? I made sure that all my snaps are up-to-date.

Thanks!